# Visual Studio 2008 - code out of sync with the location for debug source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I've checked out a tag for a [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008) project into a new local folder. (The local folder is different than where I normally work on HEAD code.)

I did a 'clean' and 'rebuild' on the project -- which created a DLL file. It rebuilt successfully and is located in the correct build area.

When I look at the files in [Solution Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools), it shows the correct absolute path for all the files within the new folder.

The problem is that when I set a breakpoint and try to debug the code, it never hits the breakpoint. When I right click on the breakpoint and look at 'Location' it shows me a path to where the file had been in the HEAD area when it was uploaded into [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion). I don't see where it is getting that old path from.

Comment: Are you sure the right DLL is loaded? Have you tried deliberately changing some code and building to see if the output REALLY changes? Also, if there are multiple projects, with some referencing the others, I'd double-check the output paths of the DLLs, I once went crazy because one of my projects were outputting to another directory, which created a very similar problem.

Comment: Rename the hidden .suo file in the solution directory.

Comment: I tried deleting the .suo file and it didn't help.
Even before I run "Start Debugging" I can right click where I have a breakpoint and look at the location path and it shows the old path.  I can see the dll being built and it has a current timestamp.

Comment: OK.  I think it actually was Hans' suggestion of deleting the .suo file that did it.  After I closed the solution and reopened it, then it seems to be picking up the correct path now.  I initally deleted the .suo file and just did a clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small checklist of things that can go wrong:

1. Verify loaded Modules (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> usually). See that your code modules are loaded from where you expect them to load.
2. When doing clean/rebuild, only the project's output is cleaned (if I have `MyAssembly` project that builds a `MyASsembly.dll`, only the file relevant for this project will be removed. Any other assemblies that are referenced are not deleted in the cleanup process.
3. Try to isolate the issue. Start debugging with <kbd>F10</kbd> (step into the debugged code). See if the entry point is OK, but only some other code that you're trying to hit is taken from the wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

After firing up the debugger, it might help to use menu *Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Modules* to see exactly where Visual Studio is loading the assembly from.

Also, verify that you are building in Debug mode. I hate to admit that occasionally I build in Release mode and then wonder why the debugger does not stop at breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio editor does not understand unix style end of line. try to use unix2dos util on the misbehaving source files.

Comment: This seriously did fix my problem.